# socket.io join/leave

Tags: socket.io

I'm on the socket.io wiki looking into using rooms but join and leave are not working, i'm wondering if they may have changed up a few things but not had the chance to update the wiki?

```
socket.join("room-"+data.meid);
socket.leave("room-"+meid);
```

cause im getting console errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SocketNamespace> has no method 'leave' 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SocketNamespace> has no method 'join'
```

Comment: Please see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251445/3904109

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're probably not declaring 'socket' correctly either that of you haven't installed Socket-io correctly. Try the following...

```
var io = require("socket.io");

var socket = io.listen(80);

socket.join('room');

socket.leave('room');
```

There's a useful executable example [here](https://gist.github.com/crabasa/2896891).

Answer (score 65):

It looks like you had the socket.join on the client side. Its a server side function.

Put this on the server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('subscribe', function(data) { socket.join(data.room); })

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function(data) { socket.leave(data.room); })

});

setInterval(function(){
    io.sockets.in('global').emit('roomChanged', { chicken: 'tasty' });
}, 1000);
```

And this on the client:

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.emit("subscribe", { room: "global" });

socket.on("roomChanged", function(data) {
    console.log("roomChanged", data);
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the `setInterval()` function does and its purpose?  I am reading it as `every 1 second send a message to all clients (in a room called global?) called roomChanged with the value chicken: tasty`, but i don't understand what that would achieve.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. Probably just to ping the client

Comment: Can u please explain will this help in getting data live from Mysql db and show it in UI ? Will this avoid SetInterval which runs for 1 sec ?