# How to create namespaces/rooms from the client using node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

what I want to do is be able to create a room from the client but as if it was an object. For example:
I have a class called "room", this class has let's say 3 events implemented so when you create a new room you can trigger those events in each. 
Is this possible? Here's my server code:

```
var express= require('express');
var app= express();
var server=require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var channel= io.of('/arduino');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

server.listen(80, function(){
  console.log("Server corriendo en puerto 80");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Se conecto alguien por Socket");

  socket.on('new-message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Nuevo mensaje");
    socket.emit('messages', data);
  });

  socket.on('JSON', function (data) {
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data);
    var parsed = ParseJson(jsonStr);
    console.log(parsed);
  });
});


channel.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Se conectaron al canal 'arduino' ");
    socket.on('new-message', function(data){
              console.log("Sensor:");
              console.log(data);
              channel.emit("messages", data);
      });
});


app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  console.log('555555555');
    res.status(200).send('GET TEST');
  });

app.post('/',function(req,res){
  console.log("post TEST");
  datos=req.body;
  console.log(datos);
  res.end("fin");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the difference between rooms and namespaces is important for deciding what to go with :

> **namespaces** are connected to by the client using io.connect(urlAndNsp)
> (the client will be added to that namespace only if it already exists
> on the server)
>
> **rooms** can be joined only on the server side (although creating an API
> on the server side to enable clients to join is straightforward)

You can define socket events specific for a namespace, but the client wont be able to connect if that namespace hasn't been defined previously in the server-side.

**Read More :** [Rooms vs Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751954/2976093)

---

I think that the easiest solution for handling different channels, including dynamic channel names (created from the client) is to use **rooms**

## Room Join/Leave from Client :

A socket.io-client can be subscribed to multiple rooms, I gave an answer with a method for :

[Making `server.side room subscribe/unsubscribe` events that can be triggered from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45546567/2976093)

It also explains how to get correctly the list of rooms a disconnecting client was subscribed to so a message to those rooms may be delivered to notify the client left.

Comment: Thank you! I honestly thought rooms and namespaces were the same thing, I'm only a beginner as you can see. This solves it.